# Django | CSRF Verification Failed

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I'm building a Django powered blog-like app for practice and learning.  I'm working on setting up a form for users to leave comments on posts.  I have a Post model that takes in a User foreign key, and a Comment model that takes in a User foreign key and a Post foreign key (to identify the post the comment is tied to).

I know the way I have it setup is not yet functional, but I'm just trying to debug a CSRF issue I keep having.  Here's my code:

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def post_detail(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("posted")
        return redirect('Home')
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'post': Post.objects.get(id=post_id),
        'comments': Comment.objects.order_by('date_posted'),
        'comment_form': comment_form
    }
    return render(request, 'feed/postdetail.html', context)
```

template, "postdetail.html"

```
<form method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
    <div class=comment-line>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form }}
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I DO have the following in my middleware

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

I keep getting an error stating, "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted" for the reason "CSRF token missing or incorrect."  This only happens when I click the post button.

I'm only just learning Django, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the issue is the "enctype" in my form tag.  Removing this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your html form and add the CSRF validation like this

```
<form method="POST" enctype="text/plain">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class=comment-line>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form }}
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I added this {% csrf_token %} to have the card token in you template

Comment: I tried this, but it still didn't seem to fix the issue.  However, it fixed it just to removed the "enctype" from the form tag.  Thank you!

Comment: happy coding ^_^